# how is Django persistent database connections thread safe?

Tags: django, multithreading, django-orm, thread-local

In django, persistent db connections are implemented by `threading.local`. This code resides in the class `django.db.utils.ConnectionHandler`. Since this class is instantiated in `django.db.__init.__.py` it gets instantiated when we do `import django.db`. And this would happen somewhere during request/response cycle. For subsequent requests in same thread or even different thread in same process `django.db.__init__.py` won't be executed since it is already loaded.

So my question is wouldn't it share the connection for all threads in same process. Am I missing something here?

I think something like following should work just fine instead

```
# file db/__init__.py
connections = threading.local()
connections.connections = ConnectionHandler()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ConnectionHandler` is not a connection -- it only handles connections. It does so in a perfectly thread-safe manner by storing them on `self._connections`, which is a `thread.local` instance.

The `ConnectionHandler` overrides `__getitem__` to support thread-local connections. When you access `connections['default']`, it looks if the `default` attribute exists on `self._connections`, which is a thread local. If it does, that would be the connection to the default database for the current thread. If it doesn't, it'll create a new one and set it on `self._connections`. Other threads won't be able to access this connection, since it's set on a thread local object.

In the end it pretty much comes down to the public API. Setting a `ConnectionHandler` on a thread-local object would work as well, but the public API would be more complicated than it currently is, since user code would manually need to check if the handler for the current thread exists.

Comment: Yes, but does every request/response cycle populate the `connections` object? I am under impression that it is populated during `import django.db`

Comment: Yes! got it. So nothing is populated during `import django.db` except that `connections` object is instantiated. And it lazily loads the connection when `connections['default']` is encountered in code.